# How do I sort multiple columns of data by one criteria?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a list of data in Sheet1 that contains a number and a name. In Sheet2, I want to print the names of the three highest numbers. Some of the numbers may be the same, and that is okay, I still want the three highest names to be printed. How do I go about this?

```
=INDEX(SORT(Sheet1!$J$3:$J$97,1,FALSE),1,0)
=INDEX(SORT(Sheet1!$J$3:$J$97,1,FALSE),2,0)
=INDEX(SORT(Sheet1!$J$3:$J$97,1,FALSE),3,0)
```

I am using these to print the three highest values

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$3:$A$100, MATCH($A1, Sheet1!$J$3:$J$97, 0))
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$3:$A$100, MATCH($A2, Sheet1!$J$3:$J$97, 0))
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$3:$A$100, MATCH($A3, Sheet1!$J$3:$J$97, 0))
```

I was using these to find the numbers and return the name, however, when there are duplicate numbers, it will not fetch the correct corresponding number.

Comment: I cannot, however, I can clarify some things. J3:J97 are where the values are on Sheet1. A3:A100 are where the names are on Sheet1. A1:A3 are where the highest values are printed on Sheet2

Answer (score 0):

Use sortn. Here's an example using the sample data from Google's [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7354624?hl=en)

```
=SORTN(Sheet11!A2:B6, 3, 0, Sheet11!B2:B6, FALSE)
```

[image]

There are other options in case you want (for example) to include everyone with  score of 80.

Original data:

[image]